# How to handle car insurance when driving a car around Central America?

Tags: driving, insurance, central-america

Assume a French citizen and US legal permanent resident with no special visa, work permit, or residence in Central America, wishing to drive a car around the 7 countries of Central America for 1 or several weeks. Assume that there is no COVID-19 pandemic.

How to handle car insurance when driving around Central America? E.g., should the traveler obtain car insurance that is valid for the entire Central America, or instead obtain car insurance for each of the seven countries? If the latter, can the insurance be obtained when entering a new country, or should it be required ahead of time? If the latter, is  there any way to conveniently subscribe to multiple car insurances at once (1 insurance/country)?

---

Response to comments:

- It takes only [30h](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Guatemala/Panama+City,+Panama/@11.3193546,-89.5137037,6z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x8589a180655c3345:0x4a72c7815b867b25!2m2!1d-90.5068824!2d14.6349149!1m5!1m1!1s0x8faca8f1dbe80363:0xaba25df1f042c10e!2m2!1d-79.5198696!2d8.9823792!3e0) to cross Central America when respecting the speed limit.
- "Would this be your own car or a rental car? Would you also be driving through Mexico?": Most likely car rental starting from Central America as Mexico is a long drive ([50h](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/San+Diego,+CA/Guatemala/@24.0954152,-112.6651331,5z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x80d9530fad921e4b:0xd3a21fdfd15df79!2m2!1d-117.1610838!2d32.715738!1m5!1m1!1s0x8588135036e7506b:0x35982b375b84d5bb!2m2!1d-90.230759!2d15.783471!3e0)) + might remove my UV tints.

Comment: I'm going to have to ask if this is actually a real situation you are trying to address for a specific trip, or simply just a theoretical thought experiment that is of no practical use to anyone.  Because IMHO both this and your covid question have the hallmarks of the latter and not the former.  Feel free to change my mind about it being a serious question about definite travel plans.

Comment: @PeterM the question is serious. Central America seems quite small and drivable. And the covid question is a natural complement.

Comment: My skepticism is rooted in the vagueness of your proposed trip, in both destination and duration (1 week? seriously?!?! that in itself screams not serious to me).  If you had stated your question in concrete terms then I would be less skeptical.  EG phrasing it something like "After covid has settled down, in 2022  I intend to drive from the US to Panama and return in my own car, taking 2 months for the trip.  Will I need any insurance in addition to my normal US policy for each of the 7 central american countries? And where and when can I obtain it?".

Comment: @PeterM takes only [30h](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Guatemala/Panama+City,+Panama/@11.3193546,-89.5137037,6z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x8589a180655c3345:0x4a72c7815b867b25!2m2!1d-90.5068824!2d14.6349149!1m5!1m1!1s0x8faca8f1dbe80363:0xaba25df1f042c10e!2m2!1d-79.5198696!2d8.9823792!3e0) to cross Central Americal  when respecting the speed limit.

Comment: @PeterM Should it take two months to drive from Albuquerque to San Francisco, a similar distance?! What makes one road trip "real" and the other not?